# How do you create many records at once using Prisma2?

Tags: prisma, prisma2

I'm new to Prisma 2 and I'm wondering how do I create many records using the prisma client? It doesn't seem to have any documentation around this use case, but there are docs for [updateMany](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/tools-and-interfaces/prisma-client/crud#updatemany).